# ORM init() function pass args on entityNew

Tags: coldfusion

Is it possible to pass arguments to a entity in ORM like my example below? I was hoping something like this would work.....

pass in args

```
entityNew(arguments.entityName).init(valueHere);
```

then get it here in the entity init() function.

```
property name="ID"  type="string"    fieldtype="id" generator="guid";
property name="val1"    type="string"     ormtype="string"  persistent=true;

property name="val2"    type="any"      persistent=false    default="";

 public statsEntity function init(){

    // do something with it
    variables.val2= arguments.value;

  return Super.init();
}
```

Comment: make sure you add `if(isDefined("arguments.value"))` before you access it.  You must *NOT* have any required argument(s) in the `init()` otherwise entityNew() will crap out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The init function will run by default.

As of ColdFusion 9.0.1 you can do this:

```
entityNew( "nameOfEntity", { arg1=val1, arg2=val2 } );
```

You could also use the new operator, which also runs the init if exists, although you need the full path:

```
obj = new path.nameOfEntity( arg1=val1, arg2=val2 );
```

Comment: note that this will not invoke your setter(s), so no validation is done using this method of populating an entity.

Comment: would the value be passed for all the entities in my array?

Comment: @Henry: Correct it invokes the init() function where you can do what you like.

Comment: @Niklas I'm not sure what you mean. Whatever is passed in will be available to the init function.

Comment: @SamFarmer yes, I should clarify what I meant is that this method ignores the `validate` and the `validateparams` attributes in cfproperty which are normally run by the implicit setters.